# JQuery append to IMG URL, this works, but Developer Console reports 404 errors. How to stop those errors?

Tags: html, jquery, image, console

The images are from a markdown template and the SRC once parsed is just the filename only, no complete URL. I append the URL with the JQuery below, and the image is loaded as expected. The issue isn't that the image file doesn't exist, it does, but the developer console reports the file not found. And because of this, the browser fails to load other dependencies, such as the RRSSB plugin, for example.

Anyone got any suggestions please? Here is the JQuery below:

```
$(".markdown").find("img").each(function() 
        { 
            $(this).addClass("markdown");
            $(this).attr("src", function(i, value) 
            {
                return "{{ config("website.aws.s3") }}" + value;
            });
        });
```

As I said, the actual image itself is loaded without any problems. I just need the console not to report the 404 error, that's all.

Comment: _"...and the SRC once parsed is just the filename only,"_ - And that's the source for those `404`s. _"the browser fails to load other dependencies, such as the RRSSB plugin"_ - A `404` doesn't stop the browser to load other stuff. If that plugin cannot handle missing/broken images then I would try to find a different plugin or init the plugin _after_ you've fixed the images.

Comment: Thanks, the plugin loads okay but I'm seeing the font it uses, isn't loading. I'll try your suggestion :)